# Custom Week Number in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to add a column to my data set that has a custom week number based on a specific start date.

For example, lets say that that a product launched Thursday September 6, and I want to measure signups by week. In this case, I would want September 6 - September 12 to be Week 1, September 13 - 19 as week 2, etc.

The two options I have found are using the datefirst function and creating a custom calendar table, but which of these would be easier to implement and more efficient?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't `date_diff(week, start_date, column_date)` get you the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Much better if you use date first - date end so that the users can also understand it easily.